# No URL path binder found for type Option[Long]. Try to implement an implicit PathBindable for this type

Tags: scala, play2-mini

```
GET /home/:id/delete        controllers.Application.delete(id:Option[Long])
```

I am working on play 2.1 framework with scala and this error occurs . how to solve it

Comment: I think you should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980952/routes-with-optional-parameter-play-2-1-scala

Comment: @rahul if you solved it, is a good pratice to share this knowledge here

Comment: @rahul how did you solve it

Comment: no solution --> downvoting question

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `Option[]` like below url

```
GET /home/:id/delete        controllers.Application.delete(id:Long)
```