# Optional named parameter in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

In Rails I can say:

```
get 'path1/:path2/(:path3)' => "controller#action"
```

where `path3` is an optional **named** parameter and there is a slash before it. In Play Framework I only found the way to do something like this but only for parameters with `?`.

How do I do that in Play Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for optional path parameters has been dropped with 2.1, [see](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/1007-Routes-with-Option-do-not-compile-Play-21-Scala):

> We removed Option[...] support in path bindables since it doesn't make sense to have a optional path parameter. You can implement your own path bindable that supports it if you please.

A possible solution (which is implementing a bindable yourself) is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980952/routes-with-optional-parameter-play-2-1-scala).

But the simplest solution might be to simply define two routes:

```
GET   /path/:a                   controllers.Application.show(a, b = "default")
GET   /path/:a/:b                controllers.Application.show(a, b)
```

By the way, the things you are referring to are path parameters and query parameters (the part after `?` in an URL). [Named parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/named-parameters.html) are a completely different (and unrelated) story.

Comment: what if there is no default value (I don't and shouldn't know the default value)? this should be a completely optional parameter.

Comment: Well you want to do different things depending if the parameter is set or not, right, as otherwise it would be completely useless to have it in the first place. So you can simply route the two paths to different controller functions that do the appropriate job, I really don't see the difficulty here

Comment: why not to use just `GET   /path/:a                   controllers.Application.show(a)` instead of using a default parameter?

Comment: That was exactly my suggestion from the comment. But it implies that you have to overloaded versions of show, one that takes one and one that takes two parameters.