# Routes overloading doesn't work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I want to be able to have this:

```
POST /items controllers.Application.update()
POST /items/:itemType controllers.Application.update(itemType: String)
POST /items/:itemType/:id controllers.Application.update(itemType: String, id: Int)
```

but that doesn't compile due to the error of `method update is defined twice`. Then I changed it and it didn't compiler either:

```
POST /items controllers.Application.update(itemType: Option[String] = None, id: Option[Int] = None)
POST /items/:itemType controllers.Application.update(itemType: String, id: Option[Int] = None)
POST /items/:itemType/:id controllers.Application.update(itemType: String, id: Int)
```

the errors are:

1. the previouse one
2. and `type mismatch;  found: Option[String]; required: String`

What do I do about that? I **wouldn't** like to do something like this:

```
POST /items controllers.Application.updateAll()
POST /items/:itemType controllers.Application.updateByType(itemType: String)
POST /items/:itemType/:id controllers.Application.updateByTypeAndId(itemType: String, id: Int)
```

and this **doesn't** look good either since I'd like to use `Option` instead of the empty string:

```
POST /items controllers.Application.update(itemType: String = "", id: Int = "")
POST /items/:itemType/:id controllers.Application.update(itemType: String, id: Int = "")
POST /items/:itemType/:id controllers.Application.update(itemType: String, id: Int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems support for Option was removed in v2 - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980952/routes-with-optional-parameter-play-2-1-scala) for example - so you may be stuck with either coding your own `PathBindable` to handle Options (as mentioned in the above link), or one of the other unsavoury choices you've noted.

Comment: can I cast the parameters from url to a certain type? `(itemType: MyClass1, id: MyClass2)`

Comment: Sorry, I've never looked into that myself, so I couldn't say.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to change your URL format, you have the ability to use Option.

Route: `POST /items controllers.Application.update(itemType: Option[String], id: Option[Int])`

URL: `http://localhost:9000/items?itemType=someItem&id=123`

With this format, you are able to omit itemType, id, or both when making the web service call.

Comment: I want there to be "/" and not "?".

Comment: I understand. It's much cleaner that way. I wanted to present the option in case you (or others looking for a solution in the future) had/have a need to use Options.