# Evaluate a default parameter at runtime

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.2

I have a following route which is not what I am looking for:

```
GET   /                     controllers.Application.index(someParam = "???")
GET   /:someParam           controllers.Application.index(someParam)
```

**The value of `someParam` is unknown at compile time thus it should be evaluated at runtime.**

In fact, what I'd like to do is that, `index` must always redirects to `index/someParam`. So if an user goes to `/` (root path), they get redirected to `/someParam` (`someParam` is evaluated at runtime). If they go to `/someWrongParam`, they also get redirected to `/someRightParam`, meaning `someParam` can be within some finite set of values. I hope that's not too complicated.

I saw this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984873/2813589 but it seemed too complex.

How can I do this?

Comment: If it is a finite set of values, can't you add a regex to your routes?

Comment: @Ashalynd, it would be too complex.

Comment: Regex too complex? then I don't know what is simple... :)

Answer (score 1):

Create two actions instead

```
GET   /                     controllers.Application.blankIndex
GET   /:someParam           controllers.Application.index(someParam)
```

the parameterless `blankIndex` action can get any value set i.e. in `onStart` method of [Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal) and then just make a [common redirect](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting) to `index` with given param.