# Play framework routes, and scala predef values

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I develop application on play framework 2.2
I have a routes file like this:

```
GET  /posting/          controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts()
GET  /posting/:number   controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int)
```

And BlogContriller:

```
object BlogController extends Controller {

  def allPosts(pageNumber:Int = 1, postsPerPage:Int = 10) = Action{
    val posts = Post.getLastNPosts(postsPerPage, postsPerPage*(pageNumber-1))
    val htmlPosts = new Html(new StringBuilder());

    for (post <- posts){
      val htmlPost = views.html.posting.post(post.getName, post.getText, post.getDate.toString)
      htmlPosts += htmlPost;
    }

    Ok(views.html.posting.index(htmlPosts))
  }
}
```

When I try to comile that, I give a error:

```
Error:(14, -1) Play 2 Compiler:  C:\...\conf\routes:14: Compilation error[Using different overloaded methods is not allowed. If you are using a single method in combination with default parameters, make sure you declare them all explicitly.]
GET  /posting/:number   controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int)
```

And I can't understand how to fix that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can must use parameter with default value:

```
GET  /posting/          controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int = 1)
GET  /posting/:number   controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int)
```

You may not use overloaded methods `allPosts(Int)` and `allPosts`. Since you declared `allPosts` with two parameters with default values, Scala sees this method as 4 different methods. You may only use one of them.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have a new error: "It is not allowed to specify a fixed or default value for parameter: 'number' extracted from the path"

Answer (score 2):

You must have all the parameters defined for same function. In your case `allPosts`. Give a default value for routes where you don't need that parameter.

```
GET  /posting/          controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int ?= 0)
```

`GET  /posting/:number   controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Optional Parameters. Something like

```
GET  /posting/          controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Option[Int])
GET  /posting/:number   controllers.posting.BlogController.allPosts(number: Int)
```

Then you can call this with or without a parameter in the query:

```
/posting?number=1
/posting
```

Make sure you declare an Option as well in your controller